# Animate*AsState slow out in the last 3 digits or last part

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

So for I'm using `animateIntAsState()` and I want the last 3 digits to be able for the user to watch how it goes up, for example.

In a range of **0..300**, I want to **go from 0..296..** and then user **sees slowly how it increments from** 296 to 297, then to 298, then to 299 and finally 300.

From the current predefined "easing", there's no way to do this, how could I make a custom one for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [keyframes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#keyframes) animation:

```
var targetValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val value by animateIntAsState(
    targetValue = targetValue,
    animationSpec = keyframes {
        durationMillis = 3000 // 3 sec
        0 at 0 with LinearOutSlowInEasing // for 0-1 sec
        296 at 1000 with LinearEasing // for 1-3 sec
    }
)
Text(value.toString())
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    // start animation in 1 sec after launch
    delay(1000)
    targetValue = 300
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed this keyframes thing sounds so much to me that I believe I've read it somewhere in the past lol, just didn't look over that this time, thank you!